# Restore fails in single mode because exclusive access cannot be obtained

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We have a script that runs every night, this is the relevant part of the script:

```sql
---- Restore DB from file system
print ''
print '----------------------------------------------'
print 'Restoring Database: $(DbName)'
print '' 
use master
alter database [$(DbName)] set single_user with rollback immediate
restore database [$(DbName)] 
    from  disk = '$(BackupFile)' 
    with replace,
    move @datalogname TO @datapath,
    move @loglogname TO @logpath,
    stats = 5
alter database [$(DbName)] set multi_user
alter database [$(DbName)] set new_broker with rollback immediate
print '----------------------------------------------'
```

Most of the nights it works. On some nights it fails with the following output:

```
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] ----------------------------------------------
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Restoring Database: MYDATABASE
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7]  
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER, Line 83
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER, Line 83
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Msg 1205, Level 13, State 68, Server MYSERVER, Line 89
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER, Line 89
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
[04:00:29] :     [Step 2/7] ----------------------------------------------
```

Line 83 is the RESTORE statement. Line 89 is the `set multi_user` statement.

Why is this happening and how do we make sure it succeeds every time.

**UPDATE**

No explicit transactions are defined in the script. The script is run with `sqlcmd` from a file. There are several processes outside of the SQL Server VM that are polling the database regularly, and my guess is that one of them manage to butt in between `set single_user` and `restore` when this happens. It was suggested that it can be solved by temporarily enabling a rule on local firewall that prohibits incoming connections, but I'm wondering if there is a SQL only solution.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I Think the issue is that there are several processes (10+) polling this DB, so the moment you set it back to multi_user someone gets connected and it does not work. It is not practical for us to pause all these processes since they are all over. A local firewall solution was suggested, but I wonder if this can be done on Sql Server level. Thank you for you help, Aaron, I always enjoy reading your responses.

Comment: @AaronBertrand unfortunately most of the service accounts have db_owner permissions, not sa though.

Comment: Why not a simple script that stops/restarts these polling processes?

Comment: @SMor, yes, Aaron's explanation, is exactly why for us.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Difficult - yes, More difficult when there is no cohesive plan for implementing and documenting who does what and where it runs. A good disaster recover plan seems like an urgent need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to restore a copy (always calculating new data/log file path names with date/time embedded to avoid collisions), then you can simply kick the users out, drop the old version, and rename the copy, without any delays associated with the start of the restore being a potential cause for letting persistent connections in before it can actually try to gain exclusive access:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [$(DbName)_copy] 
    FROM DISK = '$(BackupFile)' 
    WITH REPLACE, -- not really necessary, unless last night failed
    MOVE @datalogname TO @datapath, -- change this calc to include date/time
    MOVE @loglogname  TO @logpath,  -- change this calc to include date/time
    STATS = 5;

ALTER DATABASE [$(DbName)_copy] SET NEW_BROKER; -- before anyone can try

ALTER DATABASE [$(DbName)] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

DROP DATABASE [$(DbName)];

ALTER DATABASE [$(DbName)_copy] MODIFY NAME = [$(DbName)];
```

If this still doesn't let you through, you can either:

- use a loop to continuously try to kick the users out and drop the database, e.g.

  ```
  DECLARE @i int = 1;
  WHILE @i <= 100
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
      ALTER DATABASE [$(DbName)] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
      DROP DATABASE [$(DbName)];
      SET @i = 100;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      SET @i += 1;
      PRINT 'failed';
    END CATCH
  END
  ```
- disable the logins and/or create a logon trigger that temporarily rejects everyone but you (or at least slows them down) - but be careful, it's easy to lock everyone out
- restart the SQL Server service and simply rename the database in a startup procedure before anyone has a chance to connect - you could have such a startup procedure always enabled and it checks a flag you set somewhere, or the time. In fact the startup procedure could do all of the above logic, but only during your nightly update process.

Comment: You also can't DROP a database if anyone is connected, and there's no DROP WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE.  You could set it OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE first, but that will orphan the database files.

Comment: @David if the single_user immediately prior doesn’t prevent anyone getting in before the drop, you could still add other mitigations I mentioned above (e.g. disabling the logins and/or enabling a disruptive logon trigger _first_), and/or looping over the drop database with try/catch, or maybe if these apps are so stubborn maybe the answer is to restart the service (it is dev after all) and rename the database say in a startup procedure before any user can connect.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you should connect to the database before setting it in single-user mode in order to guarantee that *you* are the single user.  EG

```
use [$(DbName)]
alter database [$(DbName)] set single_user with rollback immediate
```

But that doesn't work here because you can't restore over the database if you're connected to it.  The next-best thing is to use RESTRICTED_USER instead of SINGLE_USER

eg

```
alter database [$(DbName)] set restricted_user  with rollback immediate
```

> Allows for only members of the db_owner fixed database role and
> dbcreator and sysadmin fixed server roles to connect to the database.
> RESTRICTED_USER doesn't limit their number. Disconnect all connections
> to the database using the timeframe specified by the ALTER DATABASE
> statement's termination clause. After the database has transitioned to
> the RESTRICTED_USER state, connection attempts by unqualified users
> are refused.

[ALTER DATABASE SET RESTRICTED_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver15)

And of course you could also DROP the database and recreate it instead of restoring over it.

Comment: Then you can fix two problems!

Comment: This is a test database restored from production overnight, a downtime required for the restore process to finish is quite acceptable, as no one expects this database to behave at that time of the night.